# Calculate the total of tickets and give a discount to student. There is a problem with function of the calculation the total and loops

Tags: python, function, loops

Ticket sales. Calculate the total, based on the number of half price and full price tickets. If the user is a student, give a 50 cent discount for each ticket. Ask user to input number of child tickets, number of adult tickets, and if the person is a student (y/n). Keep asking until user enters a 0 and a 0

```
FULL_PRICE = 10.00
HALF_PRICE = FULL_PRICE % 2
giveDiscount = True


def calculatePrice(nHalfPriceTix, nFullPriceTix, giveDiscount):
    
    if giveDiscount:
        total = (nHalfPriceTix * HALF_PRICE) + (nFullPriceTix * FULL_PRICE) - .5

    else:    
        total = (nHalfPriceTix * HALF_PRICE) + (nFullPriceTix * FULL_PRICE)
                                                
    return total

while True:
    print()
    nChildTickets = input('How many child tickets do you want? ')
    nChildTickets = int(nChildTickets)
    nAdultTickets = input('How many adult tickets do you want? ')
    nAdultTickets = int(nAdultTickets)
    if (nChildTickets == 0) or (nAdultTickets == 0):
        break

    yesOrNo = input('Are you a student (y/n)? ')
    if yesOrNo.lower() == 'y':
        isStudent = True 
    else:
        isStudent = False

    thisTotal = calculatePrice(nChildTickets, nAdultTickets)
    print('Your total is $' + thisTotal)
    print()

    totalSales = totalSales + thisTotal

    print('Total of all sales $', totalSales)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also to add on, this:

```
print('Your total is $' + thisTotal)
```

should be:

```
print('Your total is $' + str(thisTotal))
```

since the '`+`' operator in `print()` can only accept strings(not a float).

Or you could change the `+` to a `,`.

Answer (score 0):

calculatePrice function requires 3 arguments and got only two:

```
thisTotal = calculatePrice(nChildTickets, nAdultTickets)
```

so i think for that to work you need to pass isStudent because you didnt use it

```
thisTotal = calculatePrice(nChildTickets, nAdultTickets,isStudent)
```